# Nuxt basic auth does not work on Firebase

Tags: firebase, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am working on a Nuxt project which is deployed on firebase. I have basic auth configuration set up using [nuxt-basic-auth-module](https://github.com/potato4d/nuxt-basic-auth-module).

It works locally, but on firebase does not work which I do not why. Am I doing something wrong? Additional settings required? Please give me advices. Thank you very much.

nuxt.config.js

```
import colors from 'vuetify/es5/util/colors'

require('dotenv').config()

export default {
  mode: 'universal',
  head: {
    titleTemplate: '%s - ' + process.env.npm_package_name,
    title: process.env.npm_package_name || '',
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: process.env.npm_package_description || '' }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }
    ]
  },
  loading: { color: '#fff' },
  buildModules: [
    '@nuxtjs/vuetify',
    '@nuxtjs/dotenv'
  ],
  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/axios', 
    '@nuxtjs/proxy',
    'nuxt-basic-auth-module'
  ],
  build: {
    extend (config, ctx) {
    }
  },
  server: {
    port: 4000, // default: 3000
    host: '0.0.0.0' // default: localhost
  },
  env: {
    baseUrl: process.env.BASE_URL
  },
  basic: {
    name: 'basicauthusername',
    pass: 'basicauthpasswrd1234'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned on documentation, `enabled` comes with `false` value by default

```
  basic: {
    name: 'basicauthusername',
    pass: 'basicauthpasswrd1234'
    enabled: true // Add this property
  }
```

Comment: Does your app work without auth module on firebase ?