# How Can We Use nuxt-basic-auth-module In Our Staging and Dev in Firebase

Tags: firebase, vue.js, nuxt.js

In my app, I wanted to add a basic auth feature for security purposes. I used nuxt-basic-auth-module in my nuxt app with firebase. It works locally and when deployed, it does not work. I tried adding enabled: true in my nuxt.config file as what this source says: [Nuxt basic auth does not work on Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59727238/nuxt-basic-auth-does-not-work-on-firebase)

Here is my config file:

```
modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/pwa',
    'nuxt-basic-auth-module'
  ],

  basic: {
    name: 'admin',
    pass: 'samplepass',
    enabled: true
  },
  dev: process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production" && process.env.NODE_ENV === "dev",
```

My firebase nuxt app is already in SSR. Does this have something to do with server-side rendering?